# Multiple Tapestry modules in one web application

Tags: java, tapestry

Is it possible to have more than one tapestry5 module in one web application? Every Tapestry module has an AppModule.java file, which if i'm correct, is supposed to handle only one context, is it possible to have multiple of these AppModule.java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Tapestry itself is made up of multiple modules (Core, Hibernate, Upload, etc).  This explains how to bundle a set of classes to make a module:  http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5.1/tapestry-ioc/autoload.html